# Replicating red/blue image separation effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects, image-editing

[image: http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/ar0/7c7d2facd2554488bd45d5107757148d]

I was wondering if anybody would be able to explain how to create the type of image that is done here.

Does it require RGB lighting whilst taking the photograph or can it be done in Photoshop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect is basically a faux [3D anaglyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D).

To create a 3D anaglyph effect you can duplicate the image to another layer and from the Layer Style dialog blend different channels per layer (only R for the left. G and B for the right).

You can see a quick example here:

[image: 3D Anaglyph Effect]

---

Another option is to simply overlay to differently colored layers with a Multiply blending mode.

If you're using shape layers or an image with a transparent background you can simply change the fill color (or use the paint bucket or a color overlay), but since the image I'm using isn't on a transparent background I need to use a mask to make it so (You can use the method described [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/76996/52050)—You basically use the image as a mask on a solid color layer).

Once you have your two layers—in this case one red layer and one blue—simply offset one layer from the other and set the layers to "Multiply".

[image: Faux 3d Anaglyph Effect]